# What is a good pure Perl on-line or streaming statistics package?

Tags: perl, statistics, streaming

Are there any prerolled streaming statistics libraries for Perl à la: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#On-line_algorithm

I haven't found anything on CPAN yet and I really don't want to have to code one myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [Statistics::Descriptive](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics::Descriptive). The regular "sparse" version of the module (not `Statistics::Descriptive::Full`) provides statistics that are available without storing the entire dataset; variance is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RSPerl](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPerl/) module that interfaces with the R statistics package.

Comment: That package is not pure perl thus doesn't fit the question.